# What data does digikam actually share?

Tags: photo-management, face-detection, security, digikam, privacy

I am planning to switching from Lightroom to digikam as I do not like the subscription model.

So far digikam looks very interesting. After reading the privacy statement I am a bit puzzled. Amongst other things it says "For a better experience while using our Service, we may require you to provide us with certain personally identifiable information, including but not limited to pictures. "

Does someone know what data digikam is collecting?

Are they collecting data on my pictures and tags?

Do the collect data from the face recognition?

Comment: I understand your interest in the issue. I don't think that it fits the site because the central question is not specific to photography. The same questions apply to many other online services. The answers are not specifically related to photographic software. Fortunately, there are self hosted alternatives such as Darktable, Gnu Image Manipulation Program, Raw Therapee, etc. that side-step your concerns.

Comment: Have you tried contacting them via email? `digikam-users@kde.org`

Answer (score 1):

Digikam is [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software), so normally not interested in your data. As far as I can tell the privacy policy is only about using the photo uploaders (Google Drive and others) present in the application. Otherwise the app will run entirely on your computer and doesn't leak information to anyone.